# Uninstalling an (obsolete) Eclipse fragment during upgrade

Tags: eclipse, p2

I have a fragment which has been made obsolete, and I would like to create an update which uninstalls the fragment. I guessed that the right way would be to treat the fragment as a bundle, so I added the following to my p2.inf of the plugin containing installer actions:

```
instructions.install = \
    uninstallBundle(bundle:com.iar.cdt.arm.debugger.drivers.win32); \
    uninstallBundle(bundle:com.iar.ide.debugger.kernel.win32)

instructions.install.import \
    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.uninstallBundle
```

But just as the installation is about to complete, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.iar.installer.arm 0.12.0.v201110251455, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction).
No matching artifact found for: com.iar.cdt.arm.debugger.drivers.win32.
No matching artifact found for: com.iar.cdt.arm.debugger.drivers.win32.
```

Do I need to uninstall the entire hosting plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
artifacts.0.classifier=osgi.bundle
artifacts.0.name=com.iar.cdt.arm.debugger.drivers.win32
artifacts.0.version=<the version of your fragment>

instructions.install = \
    uninstallBundle(bundle:${artifact})
```

Comment: Do I need the `instructions.install.import` statement?

Comment: ...also, can I specify a version range? I want to remove any version of the fragment.

Comment: @JesperE, `instructions.install.import` could be optional. You can't use version range, the artifact of IU must be canonical.

Comment: What if the fragment isn't installed? There are at least 4 distinct version of the fragment in the wild, and I need it to gracefully be able to uninstall whichever version the user has installed.

Comment: How about releasing a new host bundle with major version increased if your fragments depend on their host with a range?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Will incrementing the host bundle major version force any attached fragment to be uninstalled? I though the fragments led a separate life from their host bundles.

Comment: Yes. The fragment can depend on the host bundle within range [1.0.0,2.0.0).

Comment: If your fragment is singleton, installing the higher version would uninstall the old versions.

Comment: Ok. Let me do some more experiments, and get back.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fragments which have been release do not have any upper version limit. So releasing a new host bundle with a version increment wont work.