# Programmatically uninstall feature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, equinox, p2

I am looking for a way to uninstall a particular feature in my product. The feature that is installed now needs to be replaced by a feature with the same name, but different version and different plugins associated with it during update - older version of product is being updated with the new one.

Doing some research I saw org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.UninstallOperation that looks like something I can use. I also saw [instructions.uninstall](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_customizing_metadata.html) phase in p2.inf that looks relevant.

Which is the preferred/better way to do feature uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misconception: the p2.inf install/uninstall instructions do **not** change the installed units, but describe the low-level actions that should be performed during an installation/uninstallation of an installable unit.

Comment: The approach of using UninstallOperation  didn't work because what I am trying to uninstall is not IU, but just a plugin. Is there a way I can use uninstallBundle as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893022/uninstalling-an-obsolete-eclipse-fragment-during-upgrade?